# how to display just one thumbnail on index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm very new to Rails, and working on my first Rails 3 project. [I watched Multiple File Uploads With Paperclip by Emerson Lackey](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads) and followed it exactly. I have my edit/new form working properly and showing thumbnails of each uploaded file. Now, on my index.html.erb file, I want to show simply the first thumbnail uploaded for each item. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<% for art_item in @art_items %>
 <tr class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %>">
    <td><%= image_tag art_item.assets[0].url(:thumb) %></td>
    <td><%= art_item.title %></td>
</tr>
```

<% end %>

Where each art_item has up to 5 images (Assets).

Obviously I don't know what I'm doing since I get an "undefined method `url' " error. Do I have to use a partial and pass in all the images as a collection?

a little more if it is helpful:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :art_item
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :large => "640x480", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Comment: Please only use tags to "tag" your post rather than putting them in the title also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead: `art_item.assets[0].asset.url(:thumb)`